# Smooth Scroll hacia el elemtento no funciona

Tags: javascript, html

al cargar mi sitio se crea un ancla que lleva al ultimo articulo
ejemplo: noticias.php?numero=3&Cargar=Ver+mas#Ancla4

Al cargar realiza el scroll hasta la ultima ancla con este codigo

```
function llamaralancla(){
  document.location.href = "#Ancla<?php echo $ancla; ?>";
}
 <body onload="llamaralancla();"></body>
```

He probado muchos codigos para que el viaje al ancla sea mas suave pero ninguno funciona, tengo este ahora el cual lo llamo en el Head desde un archivo externo

```
document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="#"]').forEach(anchor => {
anchor.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    document.querySelector(this.getAttribute('href')).scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth'
     });
 });
});
```

Se agradece cualquier ayuda, no tengo muchos conocimientos de javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Esta funcion da la funcionalidad a todos los `<a href="#aunId">` de se vayan a una determinada velocidad

```js
$('nav a').click(function(e){    
  e.preventDefault();  //evitar el eventos del enlace normal
  var strAncla=$(this).attr('href'); //id del ancla
   $('body,html').stop(true,true).animate({    
    scrollTop: $(strAncla).offset().top
   },1000);
  
 });
```

```css
header {
  height:250px;
  width:100%;
  font-family:Arial;
  font-size:16px;
}
nav {
  height:auto;
  padding:10px;
  background:#f0f0f0;
}
nav a {
  display:inline-block;
  width:150px;
  padding:6px 0;
  text-align:center;
  border-radius:3px;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#6b4f03), to(#755e23));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#755e23, #6b4f03);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#755e23, #6b4f03);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#755e23, #6b4f03);
background: linear-gradient(#755e23, #6b4f03);
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#fff;
}
nav a:hover {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#6b4f03), to(#755e23));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#6b4f03, #755e23);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#6b4f03, #755e23);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#6b4f03, #755e23);
background: linear-gradient(#6b4f03, #755e23);
-webkit-box-shadow:1px 1px 18px 1px #49380E inset;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
<nav>
  <a href="#uno" data-ancla="uno">Click me</a>
  <a href="#dos" data-ancla="dos" >Click me</a>
  <a href="#tres" data-ancla="tres">Click me</a>
</nav>
</header>  
<A name="uno" id="uno">Este es el uno </A>
<p>
  Un texto es una composición de signos codificado en un sistema de escritura (como un alfabeto) que forma una unidad de sentido . Su tamaño puede ser variable. También es texto una composición de caracteres imprimibles (con grafema) generados por un algoritmo de cifrado que, aunque no tienen sentido para cualquier persona, sí puede ser descifrado por su destinatario original. Un texto es una composición de signos codificado en un sistema de escritura (como un alfabeto) que forma una unidad de sentido . Su tamaño puede ser variable. También es texto una composición de caracteres imprimibles (con grafema) generados por un algoritmo de cifrado que, aunque no tienen sentido para cualquier persona, sí puede ser descifrado por su destinatario original. Un texto es una composición de signos codificado en un sistema de escritura (como un alfabeto) que forma una unidad de sentido . Su tamaño puede ser variable. También es texto una composición de caracteres imprimibles (con grafema) generados por un algoritmo de cifrado que, aunque no tienen sentido para cualquier persona, sí puede ser descifrado por su destinatario original. Un texto es una composición de signos codificado en un sistema de escritura (como un alfabeto) que forma una unidad de sentido . Su tamaño puede ser variable. También es texto una composición de caracteres imprimibles (con grafema) generados por un algoritmo de cifrado que, aunque no tienen sentido para cualquier persona, sí puede ser descifrado por su destinatario original. Un texto es una composición de signos codificado en un sistema de escritura (como un alfabeto) que forma una unidad de sentido . Su tamaño puede ser variable. También es texto una composición de caracteres imprimibles (con grafema) generados por un algoritmo de cifrado que, aunque no tienen sentido para cualquier persona, sí puede ser descifrado por su destinatario original.
 Un texto es una composición de signos codificado en un sistema de escritura (como un alfabeto) que forma una unidad de sentido . Su tamaño puede ser variable. También es texto una composición de caracteres imprimibles (con grafema) generados por un algoritmo de cifrado que, aunque no tienen sentido para cualquier persona, sí puede ser descifrado por su destinatario original. Un texto es una composición de signos codificado en un sistema de escritura (como un alfabeto) que forma una unidad de sentido . Su tamaño puede ser variable. También es texto una composición de caracteres imprimibles (con grafema) generados por un algoritmo de cifrado que, aunque no tienen sentido para cualquier persona, sí puede ser descifrado por su destinatario original. Un texto es una composición de signos codificado en un sistema de escritura (como un alfabeto) que forma una unidad de sentido . Su tamaño puede ser variable. También es texto una composición de caracteres imprimibles (con grafema) generados por un algoritmo de cifrado que, aunque no tienen sentido para cualquier persona, sí puede ser descifrado por su destinatario original.

Detalle de texto en inglés.
En otras palabras, un texto es un entramado de signos con una intención comunicativa que adquiere sentido en determinado contexto. Las ideas esenciales que comunica un texto están contenidas en lo que se suele denominar «macroproposiciones», unidades estructurales de nivel superior o global, que otorgan coherencia al texto constituyendo su hilo central, el esqueleto estructural que cohesiona elementos lingüísticos formales de alto nivel, como los títulos y subtítulos, la secuencia de párrafos, etc. En contraste, las «microproposiciones» son los element
</p>  
<A name="dos" id="dos">Este es el dos </A>
<p>
  Un texto es una composición de signos codificado en un sistema de escritura (como un alfabeto) que forma una unidad de sentido . Su tamaño puede ser variable. También es texto una composición de caracteres imprimibles (con grafema) generados por un algoritmo de cifrado que, aunque no tienen sentido para cualquier persona, sí puede ser descifrado por su destinatario original. Un texto es una composición de signos codificado en un sistema de escritura (como un alfabeto) que forma una unidad de sentido . Su tamaño puede ser variable. También es texto una composición de caracteres imprimibles (con grafema) generados por un algoritmo de cifrado que, aunque no tienen sentido para cualquier persona, sí puede ser descifrado por su destinatario original. Un texto es una composición de signos codificado en un sistema de escritura (como un alfabeto) que forma una unidad de sentido . Su tamaño puede ser variable. También es texto una composición de caracteres imprimibles (con grafema) generados por un algoritmo de cifrado que, aunque no tienen sentido para cualquier persona, sí puede ser descifrado por su destinatario original. Un texto es una composición de signos codificado en un sistema de escritura (como un alfabeto) que forma una unidad de sentido . Su tamaño puede ser variable. También es texto una composición de caracteres imprimibles (con grafema) generados por un algoritmo de cifrado que, aunque no tienen sentido para cualquier persona, sí puede ser descifrado por su destinatario original. Un texto es una composición de signos codificado en un sistema de escritura (como un alfabeto) que forma una unidad de sentido . Su tamaño puede ser variable. También es texto una composición de caracteres imprimibles (con grafema) generados por un algoritmo de cifrado que, aunque no tienen sentido para cualquier persona, sí puede ser descifrado por su destinatario original.

 Un texto es una composición de signos codificado en un sistema de escritura (como un alfabeto) que forma una unidad de sentido . Su tamaño puede ser variable. También es texto una composición de caracteres imprimibles (con grafema) generados por un algoritmo de cifrado que, aunque no tienen sentido para cualquier persona, sí puede ser descifrado por su destinatario original. Un texto es una composición de signos codificado en un sistema de escritura (como un alfabeto) que forma una unidad de sentido . Su tamaño puede ser variable. También es texto una composición de caracteres imprimibles (con grafema) generados por un algoritmo de cifrado que, aunque no tienen sentido para cualquier persona, sí puede ser descifrado por su destinatario original. Un texto es una composición de signos codificado en un sistema de escritura (como un alfabeto) que forma una unidad de sentido . Su tamaño puede ser variable. También es texto una composición de caracteres imprimibles (con grafema) generados por un algoritmo de cifrado que, aunque no tienen sentido para cualquier persona, sí puede ser descifrado por su destinatario original. Un texto es una composición de signos codificado en un sistema de escritura (como un alfabeto) que forma una unidad de sentido . Su tamaño puede ser variable. También es texto una composición de caracteres imprimibles (con grafema) generados por un algoritmo de cifrado que, aunque no tienen sentido para cualquier persona, sí puede ser descifrado por su destinatario original. Un texto es una composición de signos codificado en un sistema de escritura (como un alfabeto) que forma una unidad de sentido . Su tamaño puede ser variable. También es texto una composición de caracteres imprimibles (con grafema) generados por un algoritmo de cifrado que, aunque no tienen sentido para cualquier persona, sí puede ser descifrado por su destinatario original. Un texto es una composición de signos codificado en un sistema de escritura (como un alfabeto) que forma una unidad de sentido . Su tamaño puede ser variable. También es texto una composición de caracteres imprimibles (con grafema) generados por un algoritmo de cifrado que, aunque no tienen sentido para cualquier persona, sí puede ser descifrado por su destinatario original.
Detalle de texto en inglés.
En otras palabras, un texto es un entramado de signos con una intención comunicativa que adquiere sentido en determinado contexto. Las ideas esenciales que comunica un texto están contenidas en lo que se suele denominar «macroproposiciones», unidades estructurales de nivel superior o global, que otorgan coherencia al texto constituyendo su hilo central, el esqueleto estructural que cohesiona elementos lingüísticos formales de alto nivel, como los títulos y subtítulos, la secuencia de párrafos, etc. En contraste, las «microproposiciones» son los element Un texto es una composición de signos codificado en un sistema de escritura (como un alfabeto) que forma una unidad de sentido . Su tamaño puede ser variable. También es texto una composición de caracteres imprimibles (con grafema) generados por un algoritmo de cifrado que, aunque no tienen sentido para cualquier persona, sí puede ser descifrado por su destinatario original. Un texto es una composición de signos codificado en un sistema de escritura (como un alfabeto) que forma una unidad de sentido . Su tamaño puede ser variable. También es texto una composición de caracteres imprimibles (con grafema) generados por un algoritmo de cifrado que, aunque no tienen sentido para cualquier persona, sí puede ser descifrado por su destinatario original. Un texto es una composición de signos codificado en un sistema de escritura (como un alfabeto) que forma una unidad de sentido . Su tamaño puede ser variable. También es texto una composición de caracteres imprimibles (con grafema) generados por un algoritmo de cifrado que, aunque no tienen sentido para cualquier persona, sí puede ser descifrado por su destinatario original. Un texto es una composición de signos codificado en un sistema de escritura (como un alfabeto) que forma una unidad de sentido . Su tamaño puede ser variable. También es texto una composición de caracteres imprimibles (con grafema) generados por un algoritmo de cifrado que, aunque no tienen sentido para cualquier persona, sí puede ser descifrado por su destinatario original. Un texto es una composición de signos codificado en un sistema de escritura (como un alfabeto) que forma una unidad de sentido . Su tamaño puede ser variable. También es texto una composición de caracteres imprimibles (con grafema) generados por un algoritmo de cifrado que, aunque no tienen sentido para cualquier persona, sí puede ser descifrado por su destinatario original. Un texto es una composición de signos codificado en un sistema de escritura (como un alfabeto) que forma una unidad de sentido . Su tamaño puede ser variable. También es texto una composición de caracteres imprimibles (con grafema) generados por un algoritmo de cifrado que, aunque no tienen sentido para cualquier persona, sí puede ser descifrado por su destinatario original.
</p>  
<A name="tres" id="tres">Este es el tres </A>
<p>
  Un texto es una composición de signos codificado en un sistema de escritura (como un alfabeto) que forma una unidad de sentido . Su tamaño puede ser variable. También es texto una composición de caracteres imprimibles (con grafema) generados por un algoritmo de cifrado que, aunque no tienen sentido para cualquier persona, sí puede ser descifrado por su destinatario original.

 Un texto es una composición de signos codificado en un sistema de escritura (como un alfabeto) que forma una unidad de sentido . Su tamaño puede ser variable. También es texto una composición de caracteres imprimibles (con grafema) generados por un algoritmo de cifrado que, aunque no tienen sentido para cualquier persona, sí puede ser descifrado por su destinatario original. Un texto es una composición de signos codificado en un sistema de escritura (como un alfabeto) que forma una unidad de sentido . Su tamaño puede ser variable. También es texto una composición de caracteres imprimibles (con grafema) generados por un algoritmo de cifrado que, aunque no tienen sentido para cualquier persona, sí puede ser descifrado por su destinatario original. Un texto es una composición de signos codificado en un sistema de escritura (como un alfabeto) que forma una unidad de sentido . Su tamaño puede ser variable. También es texto una composición de caracteres imprimibles (con grafema) generados por un algoritmo de cifrado que, aunque no tienen sentido para cualquier persona, sí puede ser descifrado por su destinatario original. Un texto es una composición de signos codificado en un sistema de escritura (como un alfabeto) que forma una unidad de sentido . Su tamaño puede ser variable. También es texto una composición de caracteres imprimibles (con grafema) generados por un algoritmo de cifrado que, aunque no tienen sentido para cualquier persona, sí puede ser descifrado por su destinatario original. Un texto es una composición de signos codificado en un sistema de escritura (como un alfabeto) que forma una unidad de sentido . Su tamaño puede ser variable. También es texto una composición de caracteres imprimibles (con grafema) generados por un algoritmo de cifrado que, aunque no tienen sentido para cualquier persona, sí puede ser descifrado por su destinatario original. Un texto es una composición de signos codificado en un sistema de escritura (como un alfabeto) que forma una unidad de sentido . Su tamaño puede ser variable. También es texto una composición de caracteres imprimibles (con grafema) generados por un algoritmo de cifrado que, aunque no tienen sentido para cualquier persona, sí puede ser descifrado por su destinatario original. Un texto es una composición de signos codificado en un sistema de escritura (como un alfabeto) que forma una unidad de sentido . Su tamaño puede ser variable. También es texto una composición de caracteres imprimibles (con grafema) generados por un algoritmo de cifrado que, aunque no tienen sentido para cualquier persona, sí puede ser descifrado por su destinatario original.
Detalle de texto en inglés.
En otras palabras, un texto es un entramado de signos con una intención comunicativa que adquiere sentido en determinado contexto. Las ideas esenciales que comunica un texto están contenidas en lo que se suele denominar «macroproposiciones», unidades estructurales de nivel superior o global, que otorgan coherencia al texto constituyendo su hilo central, el esqueleto estructural que cohesiona elementos lingüísticos formales de alto nivel, como los títulos y subtítulos, la secuencia de párrafos, etc. En contraste, las «microproposiciones» son los element
</p>
```

Puedes modificar la velocidad para que vaya mas o menos rápido, conforme esta va mas rápido si esta mas lejos y mas lento si esta mas cerca

Comment: Lo implemente, no tengo errores de consola, tengo jquery antes y aun asi realiza  no realiza la animacion, no entiendo a que se debe. Probé en Edge y chrome y no parece ser error del navegador.

Comment: haz un ejemplo facil crea un div abajo que ponga prueba <div id="prueba"><span>prueba </span></div> y ponlo al final de tu pagina y pon arriba un  <a href="#prueba">Horario</a>

Comment: pega el salto "brusco" igual como lo hacen las otras anclas

Comment: 1 sec lo reviso

Comment: @SebastianIsmael te ha funcionado?

Comment: lamentablemente no, ejecuto este y parece funcionar pero cuando lo pego exactamente igual en mi codigo no hace el efecto https://www.codepile.net/pile/B4qLGNZ1  Este es un trozo del archivo, nose si algun js este haciendo conflicto o la verdad nose porque no funciona

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95022/discussion-between-ketemeto-and-sebastian-ismael).

Comment: He logrado hacer el scroll, al parecer no habia conflicto solo habia que colocarlo al fondo del body, pero solo funciona con la opcion click no cuando recibe el id desde el boton ver mas a la url (noticias.php?Cargar=Ver+mas#Ancla1) deberia cambiar el Jquery cuando la funcion es al cargar y no al hacer click?

Comment: claro ya depende de la funcionalidad que le quieras dar con "click" se ejecuta al hacer click al boton, al cargar "onload" al cambiar "change" .... ya depende de cuando quieras que se ejecute